# Search users in android tab host

Tags: android, web-services, jakarta-ee, android-tabhost

I've written code for `TabHost` to have values from web service and the values are added to `TableRow`. But when I search for a user, I am sending the values from spinner and text box to web service and gets the values based on my request.

The problem is that I am not able to add then to `TableRow` by creating new fresh `TableRows`. Can anyone help me find any errors in my code.

```
public class Deleteuser extends Activity{
    Webservicepath path= new Webservicepath();
    TextView userId,Userrole;
    CheckBox selectcheck;
    Spinner utype;

    ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails> userdetail= new ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails>();
    DeleteuserDetails deleteuserDetail=new DeleteuserDetails();
    alertbox alert=new alertbox();
    EditText edtTxtUserId;  
    Button userId_show,btn_user_delete,spinner_user_search;
    TableLayout userdetailTable;
    TextView[] deleteuserList;
    TextView uName,CreatedBy,CreatedDate;
    String checkedValue,selecteduserType,userid;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.delete_user);
        utype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin_delete_userType);

        userId_show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_user_delete);
        userdetailTable=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.delete_userDetails_Table);
        edtTxtUserId=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_user_delete);
        spinner_user_search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_spinner_user_search_select);
        path.setNamespace();
        path.setMethod_name("userList");
        path.setSoap_action();
        path.setUrl();
        new deteUserIdLoad().execute();
        utype.setId(10);
        edtTxtUserId.setId(20);

        userId_show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new searchuser().execute();

            }
        });
        spinner_user_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new utypesearch().execute();
            }
        });

    }
    public class deteUserIdLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails>>{
        Webservice service=new Webservice(path.getNamespace(), path.getMethod_name(), path.getUrl(), path.getSoap_action());

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
         */
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{

                SoapObject request = service.getRequest();
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = service.getEnvelope(request);
                SoapObject response = service.getResponse(envelope);
                Log.i("Service Master", response.toString());
                int count = response.getPropertyCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
                    DeleteuserDetails deleteuserDetails=new DeleteuserDetails();
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(4)!=null){
                    deleteuserDetails.setUserId(result.getPropertyAsString(4));
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(2)!=null){
                    deleteuserDetails.setUserName(result.getPropertyAsString(2));
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(3)!=null){
                        deleteuserDetails.setUserRole(result.getPropertyAsString(3));   
                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(1)!=null){
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedDate(result.getPropertyAsString(1));    
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    try {
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException npe) {
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy("null");
                    }
                    userdetail.add(deleteuserDetails);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return userdetail;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails>deleteuserDetails) {

            deleteuserList = new TextView[deleteuserDetails.size()];

            for(int i=0;i<deleteuserDetails.size();i++){

                    TableRow deleteUserRow=new TableRow(Deleteuser.this);
                    deleteUserRow.setId(i);
                    deleteUserRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    selectcheck = new CheckBox(Deleteuser.this);
                    selectcheck.setId(i);
                    selectcheck.setTag(i);

                    deleteUserRow.addView(selectcheck);

                    deleteuserList[i]=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    deleteuserList[i].setId(i);
                    deleteuserList[i].setTag(i);
                    deleteuserList[i].setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserId());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(deleteuserList[i]);

                    uName=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    uName.setId(i);
                    uName.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserName());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(uName);

                    Userrole=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    Userrole.setId(i);
                    Userrole.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    Userrole.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserRole());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(Userrole);

                    CreatedDate=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    CreatedDate.setId(i);
                    CreatedDate.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    CreatedDate.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getCreatedDate());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(CreatedDate);

                    CreatedBy=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    CreatedBy.setId(i);
                    CreatedBy.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    CreatedBy.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getCreatedBy());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(CreatedBy);
                    userdetailTable.addView(deleteUserRow,
                            new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



                    selectcheck.setOnClickListener(listener);
                    Log.i("Exception",""+i);
                }
            TableRow addcomponentrow=new TableRow(Deleteuser.this);
            addcomponentrow.setId(200);
            addcomponentrow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            Button Deletecomponentbtn=new Button(Deleteuser.this);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setText("Delete");
            Deletecomponentbtn.setId(200);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setPadding(10, 0, 20, 2);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setBackgroundColor(color.red);
            addcomponentrow.addView(Deletecomponentbtn);

            userdetailTable.addView(addcomponentrow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Deletecomponentbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new DeleteUserid().execute(checkedValue);
                }
            });



        }
        final OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                checkedValue=(String) deleteuserList[index].getText();

            }
        };


    }
    public class DeleteUserid extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            path.setNamespace();
            path.setUrl();
            path.setMethod_name("deleteuser");
            path.setSoap_action();
            selecteduserType=String.valueOf(utype.getSelectedItem());
            userid=edtTxtUserId.getText().toString();
            Log.i("selected user",selecteduserType);
            Log.i("userid",userid);
            Webservice service=new Webservice(path.getNamespace(), path.getMethod_name(), path.getUrl(), path.getSoap_action());
             SoapObject deleteUser=service.getRequest();
             PropertyInfo delete_userid=new PropertyInfo();
             delete_userid.setName("UID");
             delete_userid.setValue(checkedValue);
             deleteUser.addProperty(delete_userid);
             SoapSerializationEnvelope delete_userid_envelope=service.getEnvelope(deleteUser);
             SoapPrimitive response=service.getsoapprimitive(delete_userid_envelope);
             Log.d("UserId Deletee","res"+response);
            return response.toString();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String res){
            if(res.equals("true"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(Deleteuser.this,checkedValue+ "User Deleted Successfully", 20).show();
                userdetailTable.removeAllViews();
                new deteUserIdLoad().execute();

            }
            else
            {
                alert.generateAlert(Deleteuser.this,"Deletion Failed","Operation Failed",null);
            }
        }

    }
    public class searchuser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails>>{
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            path.setNamespace();
            path.setMethod_name("searchuser");
            path.setSoap_action();
            path.setUrl();
            selecteduserType=String.valueOf(utype.getSelectedItem());
            userid=edtTxtUserId.getText().toString();
            if(!String.valueOf(utype.getSelectedItem()).equals("select")){

            Webservice service=new Webservice(path.getNamespace(), path.getMethod_name(), path.getUrl(), path.getSoap_action());
            try{
            SoapObject searchUser=service.getRequest();
             PropertyInfo search_userid=new PropertyInfo();
             search_userid.setName("userID");
             search_userid.setValue(userid);
             searchUser.addProperty(search_userid);
            /* PropertyInfo search_utype=new PropertyInfo(); 
             search_utype.setName("utype");
             search_utype.setValue(selecteduserType);
             searchUser.addProperty(search_utype);*/
             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = service.getEnvelope(searchUser);
                SoapObject response = service.getResponse(envelope);
                int count = response.getPropertyCount();
                if(userdetail.size()>0){
                    userdetail.clear();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
                    DeleteuserDetails deleteuserDetails=new DeleteuserDetails();

                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(4)!=null){
                    deleteuserDetails.setUserId(result.getPropertyAsString(4));
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(2)!=null){
                    deleteuserDetails.setUserName(result.getPropertyAsString(2));
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(3)!=null){
                        deleteuserDetails.setUserRole(result.getPropertyAsString(3));   
                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(1)!=null){
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedDate(result.getPropertyAsString(1));    
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    try {
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException npe) {
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy("null");
                    }
                    userdetail.add(deleteuserDetails);
                }

        }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            else{
                alert.generateAlert(Deleteuser.this,"Please Enter a valid Mobile Number", "Mobile Number Required",R.drawable.noicon);

            }
            return userdetail;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails> deleteuserDetails) {
            deleteuserList = new TextView[deleteuserDetails.size()];

            for(int i=0;i<deleteuserDetails.size();i++){

                    TableRow deleteUserRow=new TableRow(Deleteuser.this);
                    deleteUserRow.setId(i);
                    deleteUserRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    selectcheck = new CheckBox(Deleteuser.this);
                    selectcheck.setId(i);
                    selectcheck.setTag(i);

                    deleteUserRow.addView(selectcheck);

                    deleteuserList[i]=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                //  deleteuserList[i].setId(i);
                    deleteuserList[i].setTag(i);
                    deleteuserList[i].setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserId());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(deleteuserList[i]);

                    uName=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    uName.setId(i);
                    uName.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserName());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(uName);

                    Userrole=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    Userrole.setId(i);
                    Userrole.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    Userrole.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserRole());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(Userrole);

                    CreatedDate=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    CreatedDate.setId(i);
                    CreatedDate.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    CreatedDate.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getCreatedDate());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(CreatedDate);

                    CreatedBy=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    CreatedBy.setId(i);
                    CreatedBy.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    CreatedBy.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getCreatedBy());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(CreatedBy);
                    userdetailTable.addView(deleteUserRow,
                            new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



                    selectcheck.setOnClickListener(listener);
                    Log.i("Exception",""+i);
                }
            TableRow addcomponentrow=new TableRow(Deleteuser.this);
            addcomponentrow.setId(200);
            addcomponentrow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            Button Deletecomponentbtn=new Button(Deleteuser.this);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setText("Delete");
            Deletecomponentbtn.setId(200);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setPadding(10, 0, 20, 2);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setBackgroundColor(color.red);
            addcomponentrow.addView(Deletecomponentbtn);

            userdetailTable.addView(addcomponentrow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Deletecomponentbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new DeleteUserid().execute(checkedValue);
                }
            });


        }
        final OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                checkedValue=(String) deleteuserList[index].getText();

            }
        };

    }
    public class utypesearch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails> >{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            path.setNamespace();
            path.setMethod_name("searchuser");
            path.setSoap_action();
            path.setUrl();
            Webservice service=new Webservice(path.getNamespace(), path.getMethod_name(), path.getUrl(), path.getSoap_action());
            selecteduserType=String.valueOf(utype.getSelectedItem());
            try{
            SoapObject searchusertype=service.getRequest();
            PropertyInfo search_userid=new PropertyInfo();
             search_userid.setName("utype");
             search_userid.setValue(selecteduserType);
             searchusertype.addProperty(search_userid);
             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = service.getEnvelope(searchusertype);
                SoapObject response = service.getResponse(envelope);
                int count = response.getPropertyCount();
                if(userdetail.size()>0){
                    userdetail.clear();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
                    DeleteuserDetails deleteuserDetails=new DeleteuserDetails();

                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(4)!=null){
                    deleteuserDetails.setUserId(result.getPropertyAsString(4));
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(2)!=null){
                    deleteuserDetails.setUserName(result.getPropertyAsString(2));
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(3)!=null){
                        deleteuserDetails.setUserRole(result.getPropertyAsString(3));   
                    }
                    if(result.getPropertyAsString(1)!=null){
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedDate(result.getPropertyAsString(1));    
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    try {
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy(result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException npe) {
                        deleteuserDetails.setCreatedBy("null");
                    }
                    userdetail.add(deleteuserDetails);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return userdetail;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<DeleteuserDetails> deleteuserDetails) {
            deleteuserList = new TextView[deleteuserDetails.size()];

            for(int i=0;i<deleteuserDetails.size();i++){

                    TableRow deleteUserRow=new TableRow(Deleteuser.this);
                    deleteUserRow.setId(i);
                    deleteUserRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    selectcheck = new CheckBox(Deleteuser.this);
                    selectcheck.setId(i);
                    selectcheck.setTag(i);

                    deleteUserRow.addView(selectcheck);

                    deleteuserList[i]=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                //  deleteuserList[i].setId(i);
                    deleteuserList[i].setTag(i);
                    deleteuserList[i].setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserId());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(deleteuserList[i]);

                    uName=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    uName.setId(i);
                    uName.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserName());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(uName);

                    Userrole=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    Userrole.setId(i);
                    Userrole.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    Userrole.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getUserRole());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(Userrole);

                    CreatedDate=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    CreatedDate.setId(i);
                    CreatedDate.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    CreatedDate.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getCreatedDate());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(CreatedDate);

                    CreatedBy=new TextView(Deleteuser.this);
                    CreatedBy.setId(i);
                    CreatedBy.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    CreatedBy.setText(deleteuserDetails.get(i).getCreatedBy());
                    deleteUserRow.addView(CreatedBy);
                    userdetailTable.addView(deleteUserRow,
                            new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



                    selectcheck.setOnClickListener(listener);
                    Log.i("Exception",""+i);
                }
            TableRow addcomponentrow=new TableRow(Deleteuser.this);
            addcomponentrow.setId(200);
            addcomponentrow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            Button Deletecomponentbtn=new Button(Deleteuser.this);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setText("Delete");
            Deletecomponentbtn.setId(200);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setPadding(10, 0, 20, 2);
            Deletecomponentbtn.setBackgroundColor(color.red);
            addcomponentrow.addView(Deletecomponentbtn);

            userdetailTable.addView(addcomponentrow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Deletecomponentbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new DeleteUserid().execute(checkedValue);
                }
            });


        }
        final OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                checkedValue=(String) deleteuserList[index].getText();

            }
        };
    }

    }
```

LOGCAT

```
12-27 14:29:36.160: W/WindowManager(59): Key dispatching timed out sending to com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation
12-27 14:29:36.160: W/WindowManager(59): Previous dispatch state: null
12-27 14:29:36.160: W/WindowManager(59): Current dispatch state: {{null to Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false} @ 1356598776162 lw=Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@4606cc18 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false}}}
12-27 14:29:36.160: W/WindowManager(59): Continuing to wait for key to be dispatched
12-27 14:29:41.169: W/WindowManager(59): Key dispatching timed out sending to com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation
12-27 14:29:41.169: W/WindowManager(59): Previous dispatch state: null
12-27 14:29:41.169: W/WindowManager(59): Current dispatch state: {{null to Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false} @ 1356598781172 lw=Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@4606cc18 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false}}}
12-27 14:29:41.169: W/WindowManager(59): Continuing to wait for key to be dispatched
12-27 14:29:46.179: W/WindowManager(59): Key dispatching timed out sending to com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation
12-27 14:29:46.179: W/WindowManager(59): Previous dispatch state: null
12-27 14:29:46.179: W/WindowManager(59): Current dispatch state: {{null to Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false} @ 1356598786183 lw=Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@4606cc18 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false}}}
12-27 14:29:46.179: W/WindowManager(59): Continuing to wait for key to be dispatched
12-27 14:29:51.190: W/WindowManager(59): Key dispatching timed out sending to com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation
12-27 14:29:51.190: W/WindowManager(59): Previous dispatch state: null
12-27 14:29:51.190: W/WindowManager(59): Current dispatch state: {{null to Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false} @ 1356598791192 lw=Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@4606cc18 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{4604d328 com.mvss.pack/com.mvss.pack.UserCreation paused=false}}}
12-27 14:29:51.190: W/WindowManager(59): Continuing to wait for key to be dispatched
12-27 14:30:23.919: W/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45fca1b0
```

The problem is that it doesnt rise any exception or force close.

Comment: in log cat or stackrace no execptions has been rised

Comment: Mojo do u have any answer

Comment: So you want to dynamically add items once you got your response from your server right?

Comment: yes thats my point but only after button click

Comment: what does the windowsmanager state

Comment: It doesn't suggest anything. However, My suggestion is to create a function which contains your `setAdapter` ad call it the first time to bind and again call it wheb you get your response

Comment: ya i agree with u thats not the exception

Comment: can u write some sample code please mojo\

Comment: I can't :( coz I'm not that much familiarized with tablelayout. Will offer you a bounty when it becomes eligible

Comment: thank u mojo for ur kind answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21796/discussion-between-mojo-and-user1858826)

Comment: I tried even to give a bounty still it went in vein :(

Comment: can you post the layout XML?